# Divide 100 by odd number - Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to divide 100 by a number, so I get the
percentage of that number to put in a variable that is
into a FOR ... and that FOR put the percentage inside an Array ... More or less This:

```js
var number = 4
var percentage = 100 / number
var somaPercentual = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  var percentage = percentage
  somaPercentual.push(percentage)
}

console.log(somaPercentual)
```

In this case my Array would come:

```
25,25,25,25
```

So I need to sum all the Array values and give 100!
So far so good ... the headache starts when the number that will be divided by 100 is an Odd number!

If the variable number is equal to 3 for example, my Array would give = 33.33, 33.33, 33.33, where the sum would give 99.99 .... and then mess it up!
This always happens when the number is odd.

Can anyone give me a light?

Comment: `100 / 3 ` cannot be precisely represented by a computer (unless you use a language that can represent ratios).

Comment: What would be your expected result?

Comment: Before thinking about it in terms of code, think about it in terms of math... If the divisor is 3, what 3 identical numbers *can exist* which would add up to 100?  What do you *want* the resulting array to look like for 3?

Comment: is `33.33, 33.33, 33.34` acceptable?

Comment: It always happens when the number is odd? What about 5?

Comment: @Jorge.V or 6 for that matter

Comment: @David Well, in math 0.99999.... with an infinite number of 9 is actually equal to 1. The problem is that on a computer you cannot really have an "infinite" anything.

Comment: But.. but 100 % 6 =/= 0.

Comment: @Adelin. is acceptable. 
But how i will put the 33.34 in the Array?

Sorry about my english :P

Comment: @EduardoRobertoFerreira see my answer, it does this 

Comment: @AndrewBone that fixed my problem! TY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind one of the numbers being a little off, to pick up the error, you can do something like this.

When it reached the last number it works out what is left to make 100 and pushes that rather than the same percentage again.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var number = document.querySelector('input').value;
  var percentage = 100 / number
  var somaPercentual = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    i < number - 1 ?
      somaPercentual.push(percentage) :
      somaPercentual.push(100 - somaPercentual.reduce((a, b) => {
        return a + b
      }));
  }

  console.log(somaPercentual)
  console.log(somaPercentual.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b
  }))
})
```

```html
<input type="number" value="3" />
<button>calc</button>
```

I hope you find this helpful

Comment: Ty @Andrew, u saved my life !

That works Fine ! Amazing !

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Math.round()` when you sum up the array elements. This will always give the sum up to `100`

```js
function sum(number){
  var percentage = 100 / number;
  var somaPercentual = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i <number; i ++) {
      somaPercentual.push(percentage);
  }
  console.log(somaPercentual);
  var sum = 0;
  somaPercentual.forEach(item => sum+=item);
  console.log(Math.round(sum));
}
sum(3);
sum(4);
sum(5);
sum(6);
```

Answer (score 0):

So when you divide the 100 by any odd number. if it not exactly divisible then it is stored as 64 bit floating number so the value will be not exact which will when you add not give you exact 100.
but in case if you divide it by a number which divide exactly like 4.234 so when you add it it will give you 100.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "sum-preserving round" like this

```js
console.clear();


function getPercentuals(number) {
  var roundingError = 0.0;
  var somaPercentual = new Array();
  for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    var percentageExact = 100 / number;
    var percentageRound = round(percentageExact);
    roundingError += percentageExact - percentageRound;
    if (roundingError > 0.01) {
      percentageRound = round(percentageRound + 0.01);
      roundingError -= 0.01;
    } else if (roundingError < -0.01) {
      percentageRound = round(percentageRound - 0.01);
      roundingError += 0.01;
    }

    somaPercentual.push(percentageRound)

  }
  return somaPercentual;
}

function round(number) {
  return Math.round(number * Math.pow(10, 2)) / Math.pow(10, 2);
}


for (num = 1; num <= 100; num++) {
  var somaPercentual = getPercentuals(num);
  var sum = 0;
  somaPercentual.forEach(item => sum += item);
  console.log(num, somaPercentual, Math.round(sum));
}
```